# Signature Pad disables checkbox

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, checkbox, ionic3, signaturepad

I am using [angular2-signaturepad](https://github.com/wulfsolter/angular2-signaturepad) library for my `Ionic 3` application and signature pad is working fine inside the application. Now, i have added dynamic html to a `div` and inside the the dynamic html currently a single checkbox but there will be more in it.

In .html file:

```
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col>
        <div class="letter-body white-space-pre-line"
                 [innerHTML]="testData | safeHtml:'html'"></div>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
  <ion-row class="patient-signature-pad-input">
    <ion-col class="singnature-pad-col">
      <signature-pad [options]="signaturePadOptions"
                     (onEndEvent)="drawCompletePat()"></signature-pad>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
```

In .ts file:

```
this.testData = "<input type='checkbox' />"
```

Now, the checkbox is rendered in the html properly but when i am trying to check the checkbox, it's not working.

But, the fun part is that, when i am removing the signature pad from the html, then i can check the checkbox easily.

**Note:** No `z-index` has been set for signature pad.

Can anyone point me out what signature pad is doing with the checkbox added using `innerHTML`?

Comment: have you checked for z-index of signature pad?

Comment: No. I have not created z-index of signature pad.

Comment: though you have not created z-index, check whether it is already set by signature-pad, also check overlapping of signature-pad container

Comment: It's happening only when i added dynamic checkbox using innerHTML to a div. But., when there is a <ion-checkbox> or <input type='checkbox'> in the html statically, i could check the checkbox.